# Prevent Mouseenter bubbling in an unorderest list of links in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, event-bubbling

I have tried a lot of different things trying to stop event bubbling on the mousenter event but still have the problem, when I hover on a link the event triggers for all the links, like all of them were hovering at the same time. Is an unordered list of links and I'm using a computed value to dynamically change the inline styles when I hover the links:

My component is something like this:

```
      <section class="categoryList">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
            <a
              @mouseenter.stop="mouseOver()"
              @mouseleave.stop="mouseOver()"
              class="category"
              :style="getStyle"
              href="#"
              @click.prevent="getCategory(category.name)"
              >{{ category.name }}</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
```

And this is the computed value:

```
const getStyle = computed(() => {
  if (props.primaryColor != undefined && props.primaryColor != "") {
    if (!hover.value) {
      return `background-color:${props.primaryColor};color:${props.secondaryColor}`;
    } else {
      return `background-color:${props.secondaryColor};color:${props.primaryColor}`;
    }
  } else {
    if (!hover.value) {
      return `background-color:#614EFB;color:white`;
    } else {
      return `background-color:#523dfa;color:white`;
    }
  }
});
```

And then a standard function to control the hover state dynamically:

```
function mouseOver() {
  hover.value = !hover.value;
}
```

Comment: Problem is not bubbling here, problem is that your `hover` state holds true/false and all of your `anchor` tags get their style from the `getStyle` function which uses `hover` to determine the provided styles, so all `anchor` tags will change simultaneously.
So the solution would be to add an `index` to each `a` tag and have a more complex state - `{ [idx] : value }`. For example: `{ 1: false, 2: true, 3: false }`. Then in the getStyle function, you'd pass the `idx` of the `a` tag. Or simply do as Nikola explained in his answer.

Comment: Many thanks @Dimitar please read my comment on Nikola's answer, maybe  is not the right  approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly try to set hover as id instead of boolean:

```js
const { ref, computed } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup()  {
    const props = ref({primaryColor: null, secondaryColor: null})
    const categories = ref([{id: 1, name: 'aaa'}, {id: 2, name: 'bbb'}, {id: 3, name: 'ccc'}])
    const hover = ref(null)
    function mouseOver(id) { hover.value = id; }
    function mouseExit() { hover.value = null }
    getCategory = () => {}
    const getStyle = (id) => {
      if (props.primaryColor != undefined && props.primaryColor != "") {
        if (id !== hover.value) {
          return `background-color:${props.primaryColor};color:${props.secondaryColor}`;
        } else {
          return id === hover.value && `background-color:${props.secondaryColor};color:${props.primaryColor}`;
        }
      } else {
        if (id !== hover.value) {
          return `background-color:#614EFB;color:white`;
        } else {
          return `background-color:red;color:white`;
        }
      }
    };
    return { props, categories, mouseOver, getStyle, getCategory, hover, mouseExit }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <section class="categoryList">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
      <a
        @mouseenter="mouseOver(category.id)"
        @mouseleave="mouseExit()"
        class="category"
        :style="getStyle(category.id)"
        href="#"
        @click.prevent="getCategory(category.name)"
        >{{ category.name }}</a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
  {{hover}}
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Nikola, the problem with your approach is that I lose the original style of the <a> elements when they are not hover. I'm assuming is because while binding the :style one of the conditions is the hover state so the original state evaluated on the getStyle computed is not affecting the element when is not hovered.

Comment: @Lowtrux hey mate, then you can use function instead computed property and pass id. Take a look at snippet again pls, I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes exactly, I was figuring that out. Just one thing in your code when you move  the mouse our of the link when the element is hover it always stays like thateven when it's not hovered. I guess at some point the hover state have to change to null again when the mouse leave the link element ?

Comment: you are right, take a look again, you can use `mouseleave` event :)